I cannot connect to Hive Server although it is running
I am using docker for running Apache Hive. And I sure that my hiveserver2 is running as it show HiveSessionID in the cmd(but it resfresh Hive Session ID sometimes I dont know if it affect). But when i run this to connect to my Hive server inside my hiveserver2 container:
beeline --verbose=true -u "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000"
I get the following error:
Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
I tried to look inside their Docker page and do everything I could but nothing ever changes. Have anyone get the same problem as mine :( And how can you solve this?

Ah I downgrade the hive image version to 3.1.3 and it's run :v
